# Spliting String into lines and check current lines along side with next line with .net

Tags: .net, string, file, csv

after spliting string into lines with '\n' how can you get what's in the next line when you are already checking the current line ?for now this what im using  with .net :

```
 WebClient Downloadurl = new WebClient();
            byte[] myDataBuffer = Downloadurl.DownloadData(url);
            string download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);
            String newfile = download.Replace("<br>", "\n");

            String path = @"E:\BI\projet\dotnet2.csv";
            try
            {
                 Create the file, or overwrite if the file exists.
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
                {
                    byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(newfile);
                    fs.Write(info,0,info.Length);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string download = null;
using (var Downloadurl = new WebClient())
{
    download = Downloadurl.DownloadString(url).Replace("<br>", "\n");
    // you may want to do something with `<p>`, too,
    // and you should do it in a way that's not case sensitive
}

string path = @"E:\BI\projet\dotnet2.csv";
using (var reader = new StringReader(download))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path, false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string line = null;
    while ( (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Do something with each line!
        // Note, this doesn't change the original string

        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you but my questing is when i m reading the each line in the while section how can get get the next line ? it means if now im in line 1 how can i point in line 2 and modifiy it if needed ?

Comment: That's what the `ReadLine()` call does. This will get all the lines.

Comment: yes i know correct if im wrong 
the readline reads the current line you are in but it can't know the current line i m askign if there is any function to do like below :
    while ( (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.substring(0,4) = "ticp") {
         line.next =  line.next+ " id"

        }

        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }

Comment: @OUSSAMABEYGAHAR You'd do this by setting and checking a flag for each line. so if the substring is `ticp`, you set the flag. If the flag is set, you append the `id` value.

Comment: thank you very much for your time i really appreaciate it, im new to this dev env so im might be stuped, 
its not that simple 
i have to check thck the ligne if it' s tick then i recover an id from it then i go to check the next line if it's scon then i add the the id i recovered until i find again tick that i can recover

Answer (score 0):

i was able to find the soltion it's like  below

```
            StreamReader st = new StreamReader(path);
        while (!st.EndOfStream)
        {
            var slpits = st.ReadLine();
            String type = slpits.Substring(0,4);

            if (type =="TICN" )
            {
                 ticketid = slpits.Substring(5, 21);
            }

            if (type =="SCON")
            {
                slpits =  slpits.Insert(5, ticketid);
            }
```